# Angular Ngx-Bootstrap v.5.5.0 Datepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have some issue about datepicker on Ngx-Bootstrap v.5.5.0

When I set local to 'th-be'. On the calendar missing 29th Feb but we have 29th of Feb for BE 2020.How I can fix it?

this problem can be seen in ngx-bootstrap website as well. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker
When th-be is chosen, the datepicker shown does not includes 29th of February.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5U3I.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFh9m.png

Comment: Please include part of your code in your question

Comment: Both links are pointing to the same URL.

Comment: this problem can be seen in ngx-bootstrap website as well. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

When th-be is chosen, the datepicker shown does not includes 29th of February.

Comment: Add some explanation of your link here is better, because the link may be broken during the time passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed in 5.6.0

Try to update to the latest version